# Is it possible to have a string in groovy by empty and not null?

Tags: groovy

I know this may be very un-groovy of me, but I need to be able to store an empty string in an array. Based on what I have found it seems like this: `string = ''` ends up being the same as this `string = null`.

Is this true or am I missing something?

If it is true, how can I initialize a string and make it empty in groovy?

Comment: This isn't true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groovy does not consider `''` as equal to `null`.

```
'' == null
===> false
```

Perhaps you read that in the context of boolean expressions, where the two are equivalent (both `if(null)` and `if('')` evaluate to false).

You can declare a string the usual way:

```
String str = ''
def str = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an empty string to an array, are you trying to perform some logic based on the values of the array that's making use of [the groovy truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth) maybe?

```
def myArr = new String[3]
myArr[0] = 'hello'
myArr[1] = ''
myArr[2] = null
myArr.each{ println it }
// prints
hello

null  
// whereas the following...
myArr.each{ if (it) println it }​ 
// prints
hello
// and nothing else
```